# React Native Error : "Variable" is read only

Tags: react-native, expo

I can't showing data as text / label on react native
and got error
[image: 1]

and here is my code

```
function ResetPasswordScreen({navigation}) {

const [email] = useState({ value: '', error: '' });
const [password, setPassword] = useState({ value: '', error: '' });

   function ResetPasswordFunction() {
        {
          fetch("http://192.168.0.18/Api/reset_password.php",{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              email : email.value,
              password : password.value
       
            })
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
           console.log(responseJson.message);
           if(responseJson.success === 1)
            {
              alert(responseJson.message)
              navigation.navigate('Settings')
            }
            else{
              alert(responseJson.message)
            }
         
             }).catch((error) => {
               console.error(error);
             });
         }         
     }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Header>Reset Password</Header>
      
      <Text style = {styles.TextComponentStyle}> { email = email.value} </Text>

      <TextInput
        label="Password"
        returnKeyType="done"
        value={password.value}
        onChangeText={password => setPassword({ value: password})}
        error={!!password.error}
        errorText={password.error}
        secureTextEntry={true}
      />
      <Button mode="contained" onPress={ResetPasswordFunction} >
        Reset Password
        </Button>
    </View>
```

Comment: `email` is a constant value, but you're trying to assign a new value here - `email = email.value`.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: Can you not just output `{ email.value }`?

Comment: nope. cause the output should be showing email as label / text

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with the line `{ email = email.value}`? It's unclear why you are setting a variable inside the rendering

Comment: i thought the value with be showing as label so i'm using email = email.value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function ResetPasswordScreen({route, navigation}) {
   const [password, setPassword] = useState({ value: '', error: '' });
   const { email } = route.params; // If getting email from navigation param [Method 1]

   // If manually set the email on mounted [Method 2]
   const [email, setEmail] = useState({ value: '', error: '' });

   useEffect(() => {
      this.setEmail(prevEmail => {
           return { ...prevEmail, value: 'some@email.com' }
      }, []); //Empty [] will make it only run when mounted
      // setEmail is done in this way to make sure value of error still exist in the object after you edited name, otherwise the object will be replaced with just having { value: 'some@email.com' }
     // I believe you need to apply this for setPassword as well
   })
   // Do not need to do the useEffect if you are using method 1


   function ResetPasswordFunction() {
        {
          fetch("http://192.168.0.18/Api/reset_password.php",{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              email : email.value,
              password : password.value
       
            })
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
           console.log(responseJson.message);
           if(responseJson.success === 1)
            {
              alert(responseJson.message)
              navigation.navigate('Settings')
            }
            else{
              alert(responseJson.message)
            }
         
             }).catch((error) => {
               console.error(error);
             });
         }         
     }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Header>Reset Password</Header>
      
      <Text style = {styles.TextComponentStyle}> {email.value} </Text>

      <TextInput
        label="Password"
        returnKeyType="done"
        value={password.value}
        onChangeText={password => setPassword({ value: password})}
        error={!!password.error}
        errorText={password.error}
        secureTextEntry={true}
      />
      <Button mode="contained" onPress={ResetPasswordFunction} >
        Reset Password
        </Button>
    </View>
```

Comment: Yup, this is it. In addition, if you ever want to actually set the variable `email` at any place (note that inside the text view isn't a good place for that anyway), you should do it like the way you did with password, and use the set function to set it instead of assigning it to directly.

Comment: well i want to make reset password without input email as text input on react native. Is it possible? Thanks for answering @Tharavink but email still not showing yet

Comment: The useState hook specified user.value as empty string. That is why the email is not showing. Usually you need to specify the hook like const [email, setEmail] = useState(() => { return { value: '', error: '' } }); Then, set the email value (I believe navigation parameter in your case). I will update my answer with this case